# how to bind data to edit controls in a from using TTreeview in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to bind data from TTreeview control to Edit control in Delphi..
When I click on submit button .Like I can edit that data and have to update it..

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentDeptID, RecordDeptID: Integer;
  RootNode, DeptNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrentDeptID := 0;
  TreeList1.Items.Clear;
  RootNode := TreeList1.Items.Add(nil, 'Departments');
  DeptNode := nil;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT sd.DeptID, sd.Name, d.Dept FROM SubDepartments sd INNER JOIN Departments d ON (sd.DeptID = d.DeptID) ORDER BY d.Dept, sd.Name';
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  try
    ADOQuery1.First;
    while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      RecordDeptID := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('DeptID').AsInteger;
      if (DeptNode = nil) or (RecordDeptID <> CurrentDeptID) then
      begin
        DeptNode := TreeList1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Dept').AsString);
        CurrentDeptID := RecordDeptID;
      end;
      TreeList1.Items.AddChild(DeptNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
      ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    ADOQuery1.Close;
  end;
```

Thank you..

Comment: What kind of data? What have you tried to do so far? Where is the code?

Comment: now I want to show that data in edit controls...

Answer (score 1):

There is no DB Treeview as standard in Delphi 7, and in any case the query you have isn't editable. If you want to use data-aware controls on your form, you will need to add an additional dataset to bind your edit controls to. You can store the key reference of the sub-department in the `TTreeItem`'s Data property.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentDeptID, RecordDeptID: Integer;
  RootNode, DeptNode, SubDeptNode : TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrentDeptID := 0;
  TreeList1.Items.Clear;
  RootNode := TreeList1.Items.Add(nil, 'Departments');
  DeptNode := nil;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT sd.DeptID, sd.Name, d.Dept FROM SubDepartments sd INNER JOIN Departments d ON (sd.DeptID = d.DeptID) ORDER BY d.Dept, sd.Name';
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  try
    ADOQuery1.First;
    while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      RecordDeptID := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('DeptID').AsInteger;
      if (DeptNode = nil) or (RecordDeptID <> CurrentDeptID) then
      begin
        DeptNode := TreeList1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Dept').AsString);
        CurrentDeptID := RecordDeptID;
      end;
      SubDeptNode := TreeList1.Items.AddChild(DeptNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
      SubDeptNode.Data := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('DeptID').AsInteger;
      ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    ADOQuery1.Close;
  end;
```

In the `OnClick` event of your Treeview you can recover the key of the Subdepartment and pass that value to your additional query :-

```
Procedure TForm1.TreeList1Click(Sender : TObject);
Var
  lNode : TTreeNode;
  lID : Integer;
Begin
  lNode := TTreeList.Selected;
  If Assigned(lNode) And (lNode.Level = 2) Then
  Begin
    lID := lNode.Data;
    // Pass this lID to your additional query.
  End;
End;
```